# How do I get access to a specific parent scope when I have nested directives?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm attempting some Angular and I still have my JQuery head on.

I have a div which contains a dropdown nav which contains a link. When the link is clicked I want the div to go away and be replaced by some ajaxed content, and I want flagged to be set on the flaggable scope.

A have created 3 nested directives, each of which has it's own scope (scope:true):

- flaggable, for the div, this AJAXes in content when flagged is set to true.
- dropdown, for the nav, this folds and unfolds the nav when the folded state is set on it's scope.
- flagButton, this sets flagged on the nearest containing flaggable element.

My question, and it's probably a simple one, is how do I get from the flagButton scope to the nearest containing flaggable scope, so that I can set the flagged parameter in the flaggable scope.

I don't want to assume the flagLink is always in a dropdown, or that there are always 3 nested scopes, there may be more.

In JQuery this would be simple, I would just use traversal to get the .closest('.flaggable') element, and set the value on that. This doesn't seem very Angular to me though. I very well may be attempting something ridiculous.

Thanks!

Comment: Some sample code of how these directives are organized in your view would be helpful.  It looks like there are multiple divs with directives.  Each div should have a controller and that is where the bool is set.  This bool can then be manipulated by the child directives through `scope`.

Comment: I was under the impression that if I set a bool on a child scope, it would be set on that scope rather than the parent scope, and that would mask the parent scope in that context.

Comment: That's true, but you don't have to set it directly on the scope, but rather like `$scope.flag = { set: false}` and in the `flagButton` scope `$scope.flag.set = true`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm being a dimwit. $scope.flag = { set: false }? How is this different to $scope.flag.set = false?

Comment: The former creates the `flag` object while the latter changes a property.

Comment: That's a smooth trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scopes inherit from each other. There's no need to know which one is the nearest flaggable scope.

E.g. you can have this in your `flaggable` scope:

```
$scope.setFlag = function(val) { ... };
```

In your `flaggable` scope you can call `$scope.setValue(val)`, because you can always be sure that this function exists.

Another approach would be setting up a controller for `flaggable` and specify `require: '^flaggable'` in the definition of your `flagButton` directive.

Comment: Ah yes, there's a setter method in the parent scope. I see now! If I had just set the flagged attribute it would have created that attribute in the child scope and masked the parent, but creating and calling a setter allows me to set it on the correct scope. Thanks!

Comment: @superluminary This doesn't make `flagButton` have an isolate scope, does it?

Comment: I was assuming flagButton would inherit from the dropdown scope, even if dropdown had an isolate scope. Is that not the case?

Comment: @superluminary That would be true only if `flagButton` was in the template of `dropdown`, but not if both are defined in the same HTML source.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** use the [`controller`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile#-controller-) and the [`require`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile#-require-) attributes in your directive directive definition objects (and [read the guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-directives-that-communicate)).